# Magento 2.1 Site not working online after a theme installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, magento2

I have just set up a private web server to host client websites on the environment is:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- MySQL 5.7
- PHP 7
- Magento 2.1

The site was completely operational until I updated the theme using themesetup from a package.

Now the site only works over my local network but does not work at all over the internet.

The site is **hyperwholesaler.com** and it keeps trying to divert to the internal server address.

I am stumped I have tried clearing all caches, indexes and flushed magento cache still no dice.

Comment: http://hyperwholesaler.com/ opens up the home page of your site. Can you please add screenshots maybe to show the issue? Or any logs? Is there a specific page that diverts to the local IP? Which theme are you using?
What have you tried other than clearing the caches? Please add some more details otherwise we cant help you.